Atlas Search using Milti Analyzer C#
I would like to seach using a wildcard serch term (eg "This i*") on the field "Description" which has a "lucene.keyword" analyzer defined using multi analyser. I have the following Index definition below
{
    "mappings": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "fields": {
            "Description": {
                "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
                "type": "string",
                "multi": {
                    "keywordAnalyzer": {
                        "analyzer": "lucene.keyword",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

In my code i have the following..
var searchDefinition = Builders<T>.Search.Wildcard(
    path:"Description",
    query: "This i*",
    allowAnalyzedField: true);

How do i specify to use the Multi Analyser option (keywordAnalyzer)? I see in the documentation to create it like below, but how do you do that using the MongoDriver when "Path" only take a string and not an object?
  "text": {
    "query": "driver",
    "path": { "value": "description", "multi": "simpleAnalyzer" }
  }


The moment i posted the question i managed to resolve it using the following.
var def = new SearchPathDefinitionBuilder<T>().Analyzer("Desription", "keywordAnalyzer");

var searchDefinition = Builders<T>.Search.Wildcard(
    path: def,
    query: "This i*",
    allowAnalyzedField: true);

